# Send RealTime data between iOS and Java App

Tags: java, ios, swift, sockets

I'm trying to connect ios App(swift)  and Pc App(java) , 
The ios App send data it got from sensors to the Pc App  in real time.
I tried Socket and firebase , but the amount of data is low (~20  ~10),
I'm looking for a connection that can send data in rate of ~ 60 per second .

with Socket,
Server side (Java App):

```
    public Server(int port) 
{ 
    // starts server and waits for a connection 
    try
    { 
        server = new ServerSocket(port); 
        System.out.println("Server started"); 

        System.out.println("Waiting..."); 

        socket = server.accept(); 

        System.out.println("Client connected"); 


        // takes input from the client socket 
        in = new BufferedReader( 
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); 
                String data = ""; 


        // reads message from client until "Over" is sent 
        while (!data.equals("Over")) 
        { 
            data=in.readLine();
            System.out.println("data: "+data); 
    } 

        System.out.println("Closing connection"); 

        // close connection 
        socket.close(); 
        in.close(); 
    } 
    catch(IOException i) 
    { 
        System.out.println(i); 
    } 
}
```

ios App :

```
@IBAction func connect(){

    let soc = DataSocket(ip: "192.168.x.xx", port: "8000")
 socketConnector.connectWith(socket: soc)

    flag = true

}

func send(message: String){
socketConnector.send(message: message)

}
```

//....

```
  func startQueuedUpdates() {

       if motion.isDeviceMotionAvailable {

        self.motion.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 60.0
```

.
.
.
.

```
if(self.flag){

  //send data 

   self.send(message: data)

}}}
```

send data :

```
func send(message: String){
let response = "\(message )\n"

     //let buff = [UInt8](message.utf8)

     let data = response.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!

    _ = data.withUnsafeBytes{ outputStream?.write($0, maxLength: data.count)


 }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and add a [example] to the question explaining what you have already tried and what part doesn't work.

Comment: My question is how is it possible to have actually a such slow rate ?!. Give us the way you did this... & maybe we could answer something

Comment: @LorisFoe ,I edited it and added code ,hope this made it more clear

Comment: @koen , it worked fine , but the amount of data that accepted by the server(java app) is small .
with socket it is ~ 20 per second .

Comment: You say "10-20", and you want "60" per second. 60 of what?

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider , of data , I send a string from the  ios App to the server side.

Comment: Data isn't a unit of measurement. I'm assuming you mean strings. How large are these strings? Are you sure you're not limited by available bandwidth? You're also dramatically limiting your program's speed with `System.out.println` and are unlikely to be able to print 60 strings per second to the console. If you want to log it, consider using a logging library that does asynchronous logging, or printing the values in bulk after you get your "Over" message: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html